# цикл for. язык с\с++

Tags: c++, c, циклы, for

Используя оператор цикла for выполните следующие задания:

1. S= 1+ 2 + 3+...+ 117; (s=6903)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{ 
  int s=1,i;
  for (i=0; i<118; i++)
    for (s=1; s=6903;s++ )
    {
      printf("%d \r  ",s);
    }
}
```

программу никак не могу написать.

Comment: В чем задача? Посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии? В своей программе вы делаете не пойми что, это сложно посчитать за осознаноую самостоятельную попытку решения учебного задания.

Comment: Включаем товарища Гаусса и считаем без циклов) Хотя, не вполне понятно, как s в задании соотносится с S

Comment: но  нужно сделать через for

Comment: Через for, тому же, любой ценой, лишь бы без усилий... Автор вопроса бы на уточняющие вопросы и непонятки хоть отреагировал

Comment: Лучше уж командовать пиратами, йохохо!!!

Comment: S= 1+ 2 + 3+...+ 117; (s=6903) - так это и есть задание.

Comment: сказали делать через for

Comment: Да, капитан! И бутылка рома... А если серьезно, распишите, что это значит? Не можем залезть к вам в голову, увы.

Comment: Используя оператор цикла for выполните следующие задания:
1) S= 1+ 2 + 3+...+ 117; (s=6903).   вот так задание выглядит.

Comment: Идите к преподавателю и консультируйтесь, мы не понимаем вас. Что значит S? Что значит s? Сумма чисел 1 до 117 действительно равна 6903, это написано прямо в "задании" - а дальше что?

Comment: Скорее всего надо посчитать сумму от 1 до 117 (и должно получиться 6903).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int s,i,d;
for (i=1; i<118; i++)
{
s=i;
d=d+s;
}
printf("%d",d);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

вам для этого не надо 2 цикла ваш код говорит первый цикл говорит что выполнить 118 раз второй цикл который никогда не выполнится так как по середине в for вы должны поставить не присовения а условную операцию.

```
int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i <= 117; i++)
 {
     sum += i;
 }
 printf("Сумма = %d",sum);
```

Comment: А если начинать с 1, а не с 0? ;)

Comment: ну хорошо начните с 1 только в условии for надо указать i < 117

Comment: Почему? Ведь 117 тоже нужно посчитать:)

Comment: `int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < 117; i++)
 {
     sum += i;
 }
sum+=117; `
как вам такой варинт и с единичкой и прибавляем 117. ))

Answer (score 4):

https://ideone.com/TqCVlN

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{ 
  for (; !puts("6903"); );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () { 
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);  // Или N = 117;
    for(;;) {
        printf("Sum = %d\n",N*(N+1)/2);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой код пояснениями

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Для кого? Ученик в классе так 7-8 должен знать сумму арифметической прогрессии, что 1+2+3+...+N = N*(N+1)/2

Comment: Я имел ввиду пояснения для автора о том, что именно он сделал не так